can service_name uniquely identify the service？
The syntax of service call：
ros2 service call <service_name> <service_type> <arguments>

I think service_type is redundant for identifying service.

It is technically possible to retrieve the service type from the name (assuming unique service names), so I think the main reason is efficiency: if the type is specified, then there is no need to retrieve the type first.
And probably also because no one deemed this important enough to spend the time to implement it. If you want, you can give it a go: the repository is here.
Keep in mind that ROS 2 is still very much being developed, and developer resources are limited. So often 'good enough' is actually best, as making that particular functionality better than 'good enough', would imply reducing developer resources on other, more important, functionality.
